# Installing local package with Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is it possible to install package from sources with something similar to `stack build package-name`? (latter works with packages on Stackage, but not with custom ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, `stack build` (within the source directory)?

Stack doesn't really have a notion of *installing* libraries though, it only installs executables. To “install” locally-sourced packages, you need to specify *what for* you want them installed: add them as dependencies to another project, via a `location:` field in the `packages:` field in that project's `stack.yaml` file.

That's arguably sensible since, one might say, there's nothing you can do with an installed library except invoking it in another Haskell project (or in a REPL, which you can get with `stack ghci`). I personally don't hold with that though, I like actually being able to say *install that library now*. Which is one of the reasons I have always stuck to good old cabal-install rather than Stack. With that, you can just

```
cabal install
```

from within the source directory.

Cabal-install has often been criticised: its local installs can easily get out of sync and then you have weird dependency conflicts and need to rebuild lots of stuff. I never found this *that much* of a problem, and anyway this has been adressed in recent Cabal through [Nix-style builds](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/), which never produce conflicts.

Comment: What about stack global project? Can global project configuration be considered as sort of local installation? I guess Stack will make all packages mentioned in global stack.yaml available to ghci if you just start it with `stack ghci` outside of project directory, but global stack.yaml will be completely overridden by project stack.yaml if one present in project directory.